# Oracle 12c Database Config Manager very slow at creating a new database

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 12c on a number of machines (Windows 10, 2012, 2016 mostly) before and created several databases on them, using the Database Config Manager, all with no real hiccups. 
However on this one machine I am facing a strange issue where the config manager gets to 59% with the following steps...

```
Copying database files: Finished
Creating and starting Oracle Instance: Finished
Completing Database Creation: In Progress
```

And that's it, it just seems to hang there. 
I have checked the 'alert_X.log and I see that every 10 minutes it adds this line

```
2019-10-17T10:32:22.090666-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 471040K, new size 481280K
```

with the size increasing. I checked the logs of other machines and I can see the same thing happens, but on them machines it's adding a new line every 1 or 2 minutes. 
I cannot see any errors in the log files, so cannot understand why on this one machine, which Oracle was installed on in the same way as the rest (we have documented steps on how to do it) why it would be so slow.

Is there any settings or config I can look at tweaking?

alert logs:

```
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =108
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is enabled
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:07:54.316926-06:00
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Cluster configuration type = NONE [2]
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.
Windows NT Version V6.2  
ORACLE_HOME =  C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
Node name           : 56ZY0X2
CPU                 : 8 - type 8664, 4 Physical Cores
Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000
Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:2862M/8051M, Ph
Using parameter settings in client-side pfile C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\CFGTOOLLOGS\DBCA\ORC1\INITORC1TEMPOMF.ORA on machine 56ZY0X2
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 640
  sga_target               = 2416M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\CFGTOOLLOGS\DBCA\ORC1\TEMPCONTROL.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "12.2.0"
  db_create_file_dest      = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\oradata"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\fast_recovery_area\ORC1"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 9546M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORC1XDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORC1"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ADMIN\ORC1\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "seeddata"
  db_unique_name           = "ORC1"
  open_cursors             = 300
  pga_aggregate_target     = 805M
  _diag_hm_rc_enabled      = FALSE
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL"
  enable_pluggable_database= TRUE
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:07:54.516372-06:00
============================================================
NOTE: PatchLevel of this instance 0
============================================================

TMON started with pid=32, OS id=8840 
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\oracle\virtual
2019-10-17T10:08:25.044601-06:00
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
2019-10-17T10:08:29.081585-06:00
Set as converted control file due to db_unique_name mismatch
Changing di2dbun from seeddata to ORC1
Network throttle feature is disabled as mount time
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Using STANDBY_ARCHIVE_DEST parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Create Relation IPS_PACKAGE_UNPACK_HISTORY
Completed: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
2019-10-17T10:09:02.188580-06:00
Full restore complete of datafile 1 to datafile copy C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF.  Elapsed time: 0:00:27
  checkpoint is 1490581
  last deallocation scn is 1284482
  Undo Optimization current scn is 1140285
2019-10-17T10:09:24.616596-06:00
Full restore complete of datafile 3 to datafile copy C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF.  Elapsed time: 0:00:14
  checkpoint is 1490581
  last deallocation scn is 1083526
2019-10-17T10:09:41.479398-06:00
Full restore complete of datafile 5 to datafile copy C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF.  Elapsed time: 0:00:16
  checkpoint is 1490581
  last deallocation scn is 1226060
  Undo Optimization current scn is 1140285
2019-10-17T10:09:51.155091-06:00
Full restore complete of datafile 7 to datafile copy C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF.  Elapsed time: 0:00:00
  checkpoint is 1490581
  last deallocation scn is 3
2019-10-17T10:09:52.173407-06:00
Shutting down instance (abort) (OS id: 15628)
License high water mark = 4
Starting ORACLE instance (normal) (OS id: 1512)
2019-10-17T10:10:26.131393-06:00
CLI notifier numLatches:13 maxDescs:1082
2019-10-17T10:10:26.139371-06:00
All SGA segments were allocated at startup
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Initial number of CPU is 8
Number of processor cores in the system is 4
Number of processor sockets in the system is 1
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =108
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is enabled
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:10:30.837467-06:00
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Cluster configuration type = NONE [2]
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.
Windows NT Version V6.2  
ORACLE_HOME =  C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
Node name           : 56ZY0X2
CPU                 : 8 - type 8664, 4 Physical Cores
Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000
Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:3369M/8051M, Ph
Using parameter settings in client-side pfile C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ADMIN\ORC1\PFILE\INIT.ORA on machine 56ZY0X2
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 640
  sga_target               = 2416M
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "12.2.0"
  db_create_file_dest      = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\oradata"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\fast_recovery_area\ORC1"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 9546M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORC1XDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORC1"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ADMIN\ORC1\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "ORC1"
  open_cursors             = 300
  pga_aggregate_target     = 805M
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL"
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:10:30.895301-06:00
============================================================
NOTE: PatchLevel of this instance 0
============================================================

starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
Starting background process TMON
2019-10-17T10:10:56.413890-06:00
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\oracle\virtual
2019-10-17T10:11:00.528389-06:00
Create controlfile reuse set database "ORC1"
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
Datafile
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF'
LOGFILE GROUP 1  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 2  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 3  SIZE 200M RESETLOGS
2019-10-17T10:11:00.531380-06:00
WARNING: Default Temporary Tablespace not specified in CREATE DATABASE command
Default Temporary Tablespace will be necessary for a locally managed database in future release
Expanded controlfile section 32 from 31 to 128 records
Requested to grow by 97 records; added 3 blocks of records
Network throttle feature is disabled as mount time

2019-10-17T10:11:00.775676-06:00
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 841524084
Completed: Create controlfile reuse set database "ORC1"
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
Datafile
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF'
LOGFILE GROUP 1  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 2  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 3  SIZE 200M RESETLOGS
2019-10-17T10:11:00.800604-06:00
zeroing database id of data file (0): C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF
zeroing database id of data file (0): C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF
zeroing database id of data file (0): C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF
zeroing database id of data file (0): C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Initial number of CPU is 8
Number of processor cores in the system is 4
Number of processor sockets in the system is 1
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =108
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is enabled
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:11:43.807504-06:00
NOTE: Using default ASM root directory ASM
NOTE: Cluster configuration type = NONE [2]
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.
Windows NT Version V6.2  
ORACLE_HOME =  C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
Node name           : 56ZY0X2
CPU                 : 8 - type 8664, 4 Physical Cores
Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000
Memory (Avail/Total): Ph:3435M/8051M, Ph
Using parameter settings in client-side pfile C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\CFGTOOLLOGS\DBCA\ORC1\INITORC1TEMP.ORA on machine 56ZY0X2
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 640
  sga_target               = 2416M
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "12.2.0"
  db_create_file_dest      = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\oradata"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\oracle\virtual\fast_recovery_area\ORC1"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 9546M
  _no_recovery_through_resetlogs= TRUE
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORC1XDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORC1"
  job_queue_processes      = 0
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ADMIN\ORC1\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "ORC1"
  open_cursors             = 300
  pga_aggregate_target     = 805M
  _enable_automatic_maintenance= 0
  _diag_hm_rc_enabled      = FALSE
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL"
NOTE: remote asm mode is local (mode 0x1; from cluster type)
2019-10-17T10:11:43.891211-06:00
============================================================
NOTE: PatchLevel of this instance 0
============================================================
 VKTM started with pid=5, OS id=14732 at elevated (Time Critical) priority
2019-10-17T10:11:48.613136-06:00
VKTM running at (5)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
2019-10-17T10:11:49.613230-06:00

MMNL started with pid=29, OS id=14240 
2019-10-17T10:12:08.035144-06:00
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
2019-10-17T10:12:09.064561-06:00
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\oracle\virtual
2019-10-17T10:12:13.197430-06:00
Create controlfile reuse set database "ORC1"
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
Datafile
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF'
LOGFILE GROUP 1  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 2  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 3  SIZE 200M RESETLOGS
2019-10-17T10:12:13.199424-06:00
WARNING: Default Temporary Tablespace not specified in CREATE DATABASE command
Default Temporary Tablespace will be necessary for a locally managed database in future release
Expanded controlfile section 32 from 31 to 128 records
Requested to grow by 97 records; added 3 blocks of records
Network throttle feature is disabled as mount time

2019-10-17T10:12:13.424982-06:00
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 841517245
Completed: Create controlfile reuse set database "ORC1"
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
Datafile
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSAUX_GTK4K6L5_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_SYSTEM_GTK4J39T_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_UNDOTBS1_GTK4KORT_.DBF',
'C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\DATAFILE\O1_MF_USERS_GTK4LH0Q_.DBF'
LOGFILE GROUP 1  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 2  SIZE 200M,
GROUP 3  SIZE 200M RESETLOGS
Stopping background process MMNL
Starting background process MMNL
2019-10-17T10:12:16.508716-06:00
alter database "ORC1" open resetlogs
RESETLOGS after incomplete recovery UNTIL CHANGE 1490581 time 03/08/2017 19:42:10
2019-10-17T10:12:17.595584-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.596581-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Clearing online redo logfile 1 C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_%U_.LOG

2019-10-17T10:12:17.612541-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.613531-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Clearing online redo logfile 2 C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_%U_.LOG

2019-10-17T10:12:17.631479-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.632476-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
Clearing online redo logfile 3 C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_3_%U_.LOG

Clearing online log 1 of thread 1 sequence number 0
2019-10-17T10:12:17.643444-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.645439-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Clearing online log 2 of thread 1 sequence number 0
2019-10-17T10:12:17.648430-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.650425-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Clearing online log 3 of thread 1 sequence number 0
2019-10-17T10:12:17.652419-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:17.654414-06:00
Errors in file C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\diag\rdbms\ORC1\ORC1\trace\ORC1_ora_4820.trc:
ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:23.323872-06:00
Clearing online redo logfile 1 complete
Clearing online redo logfile 2 complete
Clearing online redo logfile 3 complete
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_GTK4Q1O5_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 1 was previously cleared
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\ORC1\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_GTK4Q3HB_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 1 was previously cleared
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_GTK4Q1O5_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 2 was previously cleared
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\ORC1\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_GTK4Q3HF_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 2 was previously cleared
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_3_GTK4Q1O9_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 3 was previously cleared
Online log C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\ORC1\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_3_GTK4Q3HC_.LOG: Thread 1 Group 3 was previously cleared
2019-10-17T10:12:23.497021-06:00
Setting recovery target incarnation to 2
2019-10-17T10:12:23.551863-06:00
Ping without log force is disabled:
  instance mounted in exclusive mode.
Initializing SCN for created control file
Database SCN compatibility initialized to 3
Endian type of dictionary set to little
2019-10-17T10:12:23.594898-06:00
Assigning activation ID 841517245 (0x322888bd)
2019-10-17T10:12:23.600880-06:00
TT00: Gap Manager starting (PID:8016)
2019-10-17T10:12:23.660911-06:00
Thread 1 opened at log sequence 1
  Current log# 1 seq# 1 mem# 0: C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_GTK4Q1O5_.LOG
  Current log# 1 seq# 1 mem# 1: C:\APP\ORACLE\VIRTUAL\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\ORC1\ORC1\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_GTK4Q3HB_.LOG
Successful open of redo thread 1
2019-10-17T10:12:23.688837-06:00
Sleep 5 seconds and then try to clear SRLs in 2 time(s)
2019-10-17T10:12:24.031848-06:00
[4820] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:8064218 end:8064328 diff:110 ms (0.1 seconds)
Dictionary check beginning
Tablespace 'TEMP' #3 found in data dictionary,
but not in the controlfile. Adding to controlfile.
Dictionary check complete
Verifying minimum file header compatibility for tablespace encryption..
Verifying file header compatibility for tablespace encryption completed for pdb 0
*********************************************************************
WARNING: The following temporary tablespaces contain no files.
         This condition can occur when a backup controlfile has
         been restored.  It may be necessary to add files to these
         tablespaces.  That can be done using the SQL statement:

         ALTER TABLESPACE <tablespace_name> ADD TEMPFILE

         Alternatively, if these temporary tablespaces are no longer
         needed, then they can be dropped.
           Empty temporary tablespace: TEMP
*********************************************************************
Database Characterset is US7ASCII
2019-10-17T10:12:24.780890-06:00
Opening with Resource Manager plan: DEFAULT_PLAN 
**********************************************************
WARNING: Files may exists in db_recovery_file_dest
that are not known to the database. Use the RMAN command
CATALOG RECOVERY AREA to re-catalog any such files.
If files cannot be cataloged, then manually delete them
using OS command.
One of the following events caused this:
1. A backup controlfile was restored.
2. A standby controlfile was restored.
3. The controlfile was re-created.
4. db_recovery_file_dest had previously been enabled and
   then disabled.
**********************************************************
2019-10-17T10:12:25.088006-06:00
replication_dependency_tracking turned off (no async multimaster replication found)
AQ Processes can not start in restrict mode
LOGSTDBY: Validating controlfile with logical metadata
LOGSTDBY: Validation complete
Global Name changed to ORC1
2019-10-17T10:12:25.476191-06:00
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 9546 MB is 6.40% used. This is a
user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
Starting background process CJQ0
2019-10-17T10:12:25.760590-06:00
CJQ0 started with pid=37, OS id=15684 
2019-10-17T10:12:26.261147-06:00
Completed: alter database "ORC1" open resetlogs
alter database rename global_name to "ORC1"
Completed: alter database rename global_name to "ORC1"
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE SIZE 20480K AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
Completed: ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE SIZE 20480K AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
Completed: ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
TABLE AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P221 (64) VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2019-11-01 00:00:00')
2019-10-17T10:12:26.857553-06:00
alter database character set INTERNAL_CONVERT AL32UTF8
2019-10-17T10:12:28.987681-06:00
Updating character set in controlfile to AL32UTF8
Synchronizing connection with database character set information
 SYS.EXTERNAL_TAB$ (PARAM_CLOB) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.RULE$ (CONDITION) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.ATTRIBUTE_TRANSFORMATIONS$ (XSL_TRANSFORMATION) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_ADV_DIRECTIVE_META (DATA) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_ADV_OBJECTS (ATTR4) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_ADV_OBJECTS (OTHER) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_ADV_RATIONALE (ATTR5) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.SMB$CONFIG (PARAMETER_DATA) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_DBU_FEATURE_METADATA (INST_CHK_LOGIC) - CLOB representation altered
Shared IO Pool defaulting to 128MB. Trying to get it from Buffer Cache for process 12976.
 SYS.WRI$_DBU_FEATURE_METADATA (USG_DET_LOGIC) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_DBU_FEATURE_USAGE (FEATURE_INFO) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_DBU_HWM_METADATA (LOGIC) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_EMX_FILES (DATA) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTHEAD_HISTORY (EXPRESSION) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.SCHEDULER$_EVENT_LOG (ADDITIONAL_INFO) - CLOB representation altered
2019-10-17T10:12:29.997825-06:00
 SYS.ORA_FCP_PARAMS$ (VALUE) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.PDB_SYNC$ (LONGSQLTXT) - CLOB representation altered
 XDB.XDB$RESOURCE (SYS_NC00027$) - CLOB representation altered
 XDB.XDB$XDB_READY (DATA) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.RADM_FPTM_LOB$ (CLOBCOL) - CLOB representation altered
 SYS.METASTYLESHEET (STYLESHEET) - CLOB representation altered
 AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED (SQL_TEXT) - CLOB representation altered
 AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED (SQL_BINDS) - CLOB representation altered
 AUDSYS.AUD$UNIFIED (RLS_INFO) - CLOB representation altered
 MDSYS.SDO_STYLES_TABLE (DEFINITION) - CLOB representation altered
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 20480K, new size 21504K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 21504K, new size 22528K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 22528K, new size 23552K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 23552K, new size 24576K
2019-10-17T10:12:31.008348-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 24576K, new size 25600K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 25600K, new size 26624K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 26624K, new size 27648K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 27648K, new size 28672K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 28672K, new size 29696K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 29696K, new size 30720K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 30720K, new size 31744K
Resize operation completed for file# 201, old size 31744K, new size 32768K
 MDSYS.SDO_COORD_OP_PARAM_VALS (PARAM_VALUE_FILE) - CLOB representation altered
 MDSYS.SDO_GEOR_XMLSCHEMA_TABLE (XMLSCHEMA) - CLOB representation altered
 MDSYS.SDO_XML_SCHEMAS (XMLSCHEMA) - CLOB representation altered
 MDSYS.SDO_XSD_TABLE (XSD_DOC) - CLOB representation altered
2019-10-17T10:12:32.156865-06:00
Refreshing type attributes with new character set information
2019-10-17T10:12:33.387314-06:00
Completed: alter database character set INTERNAL_CONVERT AL32UTF8
2019-10-17T10:12:35.988833-06:00
ALTER SYSTEM disable restricted session;
Starting background process AQPC
2019-10-17T10:12:36.040684-06:00
AQPC started with pid=38, OS id=13644 
WARNING: AQ 12C time manager not started, no enabled queue 
2019-10-17T10:12:37.251194-06:00
QPI : Found directory objects and ORACLE_HOME out of sync
QPI : Trying to patch with the current ORACLE_HOME
QPI: ------QPI Old Directories -------
QPI: OPATCH_SCRIPT_DIR:c:\ade\aime_v\oracle\QOpatch
QPI: OPATCH_LOG_DIR:c:\ade\aime_v\oracle\QOpatch
QPI: OPATCH_INST_DIR:c:\ade\aime_v\oracle\OPatch
QPI: op_scpt_path C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\QOpatch
QPI: Found QPI install at :C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\QOpatch
QPI: Self adjusting the directories
QPI: ------QPI New Directories-------
QPI: OPATCH_SCRIPT_DIR:C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\QOpatch
QPI: OPATCH_LOG_DIR:C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\log
QPI: OPATCH_INST_DIR:C:\app\oracle\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\OPatch
2019-10-17T10:12:44.168250-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 409600K, new size 419840K
2019-10-17T10:12:45.316938-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 419840K, new size 430080K
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 430080K, new size 440320K
2019-10-17T10:12:46.816614-06:00
===========================================================
Dumping current patch information
===========================================================
No patches have been applied
===========================================================
2019-10-17T10:12:47.050941-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 440320K, new size 450560K
2019-10-17T10:22:21.203177-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 450560K, new size 471040K
2019-10-17T10:32:22.090666-06:00
Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 471040K, new size 481280K
```

After nearly an hour, it has just added this to the logs

```
Fatal NI connect error 12637, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 17-OCT-2019 11:13:34
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12637

TNS-12637: Packet receive failed
    ns secondary err code: 12532
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
```

Comment: You should have checked lsnrctl status and reload most probably listener crashed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have a slow C: drive. I think the data files are automatically growing which is also pretty slow if they grow in small increments. If you have the option of sizing them larger to start with it should go faster because it will not have to resize the data files. But it probably is just a slow drive or one that is busy.

Bobby

Comment: This is expected behaviour, SYSTEM SYSAUX etc. Are created as autoextend and then objects are restored into them so the growth is expected he just has to give it more time.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal it is restoring oracle maintained objects everything that you expect to be in new database is being created. "Resize operation completed" means that autoextend just extended datafile that was being written into.

This step is completely HW dependent so give it some time.